# Using recursive and recursive helper to print user entered capital char's from texField to textArea

Tags: java, button, recursion, javafx, textarea

I wrote this java -fx program and it works perfectly without the recursive implementations. I wrote the button onAction lambda to ensure the program works correctly before converting to recursion. I've spent the last few hours trying to figure out the two required recursives and how to call them with the button.onAction lambda expression, but need a push in the right direction. Here's what I have.

```
static TextField textField = new TextField ();
static String text = textField.getText();
static TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
static Button btSubmit = new Button ("Submit");

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

Label label1 = new Label("Enter letters and I will "
        + "count the capitals.\t"); //Create textfield label.

textArea.setEditable(false);
textArea.setMaxWidth(450);
textArea.setMaxHeight(100);

HBox hbox = new HBox(); //Create hbox.
hbox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER); //Set hbox to center.
hbox.getChildren().addAll(label1, textArea, textField, 
        btSubmit); //Add children to hbox.


BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(); //Create pane.
pane.setTop(hbox); //Set hbox to top of pane.
pane.setCenter(textArea); //Set text area to center.

Scene scene = new Scene (pane, 450, 200); //Create scene.
primaryStage.setTitle("Count Capital Letters"); 
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();    

btSubmit.setOnAction(e -> {
    String text = textField.getText();
    int upperCase = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
        if (Character.isUpperCase(text.charAt(i))) upperCase++;
    }
    String numCaps = String.valueOf(upperCase);
    textArea.appendText("Number of capitals: " + numCaps);
    });
}

public static int count(char[] chars) {
    String text = textField.getText();
    chars = text.toCharArray();
    if (chars.length == 0); 
    return 0;
}
public static int count(char[] chars, int high) {
    high = 0;
    String text = textField.getText();
    chars = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        if (Character.isUpperCase(chars[i])) {
            high++;
            }
        }
    return high;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
launch(args);
}}
```

What I'm trying to do is have the button action call the recursive methods, but I'm confused on how to replace my current action with a call to the recursives.

After sleeping on it, here's what I've come up with for the two recursive methods. I knew I had two separate methods last night and that a recursive is supposed to call itself. Here's what I've changed so far.

Instead of the two separate methods:

```
public static int count(char[] chars, int high) {
     int count = 0;
     if (high < chars.length) {
          if (Character.isUpperCase(chars[high])) {
               return 1 + count;
          }
          else {
               return count(chars, high+1);
          }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Am I at least on the right track? Being required to use the two recursive methods (original and its helper) is throwing me off.

Comment: Which methods do you think are "recursive", and why? Most people would only call a method "recursive" if it called itself, at least indirectly.

Comment: I may have implemented them incorrectly. The recursive and its helper that I'm to use are the two count methods.

Comment: Neither one of those calls itself. What do you actually mean by "recursive"?

Comment: That's where I'm a bit stuck. The 2nd method is supposed to be a "recursive helper", the first is the original recursive method. The example in the book is really vague, hence my being stuck =P. I wasn't sure how to do it, but I wanted to try to bring at least something to the table.

Comment: Well, I probably shouldn't do your homework for you (this clearly isn't something your boss asked you to do). But typically a recursive method would return a value directly for one (sometimes two) very simple cases, and for other cases do a very simple computation involving the result of the same method with "smaller data". So my `count()` method would take a `String`, deal with the empty string case (an empty string has no upper case characters), and otherwise somehow invoke the same method with a shorter string.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to do my homework at all, just got myself stuck. After sleeping on it and looking again, I'll edit in what I've come up with so far at the bottom.

Comment: Wasn't intending to imply you were asking that; just that answering a question in the context of a learning assignment is different to answering a question in the context of a "real-life" problem (because the questions are asked with different aims). Will watch for the update. FWIW I think in this case you only need a single method.

Comment: I agree, but per the assignment I have to use the two (original and its helper). I feel the assignment could have picked a better problem for teaching recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your code what `high` is supposed to be. I would assume it's supposed to be the index of the last character in the character array you are going to examine (probably exclusive).

So your recursive step would really need to reduce `high`, not increase it, and you just examine `chars[high-1]` directly. You also need a termination step, which is when there are no more characters to look at.

So I would implement this as

```
private int count(char[] chars, int high) {
    // if high==0 we are looking at zero characters, so there are no upper-case characters:
    if (high == 0) {
        return 0 ;
    }

    if (Character.isUpperCase(chars[high-1])) {
        // if the last character we look at is upper-case, then the total
        // for this set of characters is one more than the total for the
        // set of characters omitting the last one:
        return 1 + count(chars, high-1);
    } else {
        // otherwise (the last character is not upper-case), the total
        // for this set of characters is the same as the total for the 
        // set of characters omitting the last one:
        return count(chars, high-1);
    }
}
```

For convenience, you could also implement

```
public int count(String text) {
    return count(text.getChars(), text.length());
}
```

and then your event handler just needs to call

```
label1.setText("Number of upper case: "+count(textField.getText()));
```

(Why on earth you made everything `static` is a whole other discussion.)

Comment: I initially had the variables as local within the start() method for creating the scene. When I had to do the new method for count(), I wasn't sure how to access the variables, so I just made them global. The only issue with this answer is that it has to also use the second count() method, its helper. I'll mark as the correct answer though because this was the nudge I needed in the right direction. Thanks James.